# ClosedXML file gets corrupted on save

Tags: c#, closedxml

I have an excel file to which I am writing some values. When I open the excel file I made few changes to the saved file, on reopening the same file the workbook gets corrupted. It gives the option to recover the file but the workbook loses its formatting I am not sure what I happening here. I have removed all the named ranges. The file itself is almost empty.

**The error it get after modifying and saving the excel file:**
Removed Part: /xl/styles.xml part with XML error.  (Styles) Undeclared prefix. Line 2, column 16069.

The files are uploaded at: https://ufile.io/jx2tw

I am using ClosedXML to read the input file "myfile.xlsx". The output is saved as "output.xlsx"

**Code:**

```
    string file_path = "";

    var tdb_workbook = new XLWorkbook(@"myfile.xlsx", XLEventTracking.Disabled);
    var tdb_ws_workbook = tdb_workbook.Worksheet("D");
    var tdb_range = tdb_ws_workbook.Range("A:A");
    var tdb_no_of_rows = tdb_range.LastRowUsed().RowNumber();


    tdb_ws_workbook.Cell(tdb_no_of_rows + 1, "A").Value = "What";
    File.Delete(@"output.xlsx");
    string savestring = "output.xlsx";
    tdb_workbook.SaveAs(@savestring);
```

Comment: What version of ClosedXML are you using?

Comment: I ran your code on the latest version of ClosedXML and it produced the expected file. So, again, what version of ClosedXML are you using?

Comment: This happened to me too. I have an excel with macros and It shows the message to repair when the file is created and I open it for the first time and it corrupts when I save. I was using 0.94.2 and Updated just now to 0.95.3 @FrancoisBotha

Comment: @RitaShroff Log an issue on the github repo and carefully and fully follow the issue template and I will look at it (I'm a ClosedXML maintainer).

Comment: Ya, this problem probably vanishes if using Office 2016. Office 2013 and below versions create this corruption problem. If the excel file is saved before closing then it's repaired the next time we open it in Office 2013 and Corrupted if the file is saved in Office 2007 and Office 2010. @FrancoisBotha

Answer (score 0):

You writing twice one or more of cell in Excel sheet thats why it lost first value so Check your logic.